# WeatherKit SDK - daytimeForecast

Tags: ios, swift, weatherkit

I'm using WeatherKit SDK for history data fetching

To get data, I'm using next code:

```
do {
    let weather = try await WeatherDataSourceWeatherKit.weatherService.weather(
        for: location,
        including: .daily(startDate: date.startOfDay, endDate: date.endOfDay)
    )
    
    let weatherDays = weather.forecast.first!

    // Data handling
}
```

If I `po` received `DayWeather` object in console, it contains useful fields `daytimeForecast` and `overnightForecast`

[image: Screenshot of DayWeather object's data]

But when I try to access this data from the code, it's unavailable:

[image: Screenshot of possible code suggestions #1][image: Screenshot of possible code suggestions #2]

**Question**:
How I can get that `daytimeForecast` from object?

Answer (score 0):

At current day (Aug 12, 2023) `daytimeForecast` and `overnightForecast` values are not available through SDK due to API access limitations

According to documentation, it's available only via WeatherKit API:
[image: Apple documentation for DayPartForecast class. List of supported platforms contains only "WeatherKit API 1.0+" value]

REST API response:
[image: Postman screenshot from WeatherKit API response. Response object contains mentioned "daytimeForecast" and "overnightForecast" objects]

I've tried few ways to access it but no success. Feel free to suggest ways to overcome it or inform me when this data will be available in public API, so I can update the answer